# Como definir o tamanho do vetor de forma dinâmica em C?

Tags: c

Em linguagem **C** eu posso definir um *vetor* especificando o tamanho por exemplo `int vet[3];` como eu posso definir o tamanho do *vetor* de forma dinâmica, por exemplo perguntando para o usuário informar o tamanho do *vetor* ?

Comment: Você pretende usar esse vetor como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente tens duas formas:

1. uso de [`malloc()` e *amigos*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3)
2. uso de [*VLA*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2), a partir de C99

Usando `malloc()` e *amigos* podes mudar o tamanho do array sempre que precisares; usando *VLA* o tamanho fica fixo depois de definido.

Usando *VLA* o array é efectivamente um array enquanto que com `malloc()` e *amigos* o que tens é um ponteiro para uma área de memória.

Exemplo com `malloc()` e *amigos*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *pa = NULL;
    size_t sa = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter size: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (scanf("%zu", &sa) != 1) break;
        pa = malloc(sa * sizeof *pa);
        if (pa == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "erro na alocacao\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // usa pa
        // desde pa[0] ate pa[sa - 1]
        free(pa);
    }
}
```

Exemplo com *VLA*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t sa = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter size: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (scanf("%zu", &sa) != 1) break;
        int arr[sa];
        // usa arr
        // desde arr[0] ate arr[sa - 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 5):

Para alocar um vetor dinamicamente você deve usar a função `malloc` ou `calloc`.
Você deve saber operar ponteiros para entender brevemente como funciona.

Por exemplo, para alocar um vetor com 10 posições de inteiro:

`int *vetor = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);`

A mesma coisa pode ser feita com a função `calloc` assim:

`int *vetor = calloc (10,sizeof(int))`

Você pode alterar o valor `10` para alguma variável que você leu do usuário anteriormente.

O acesso as posições do vetor é feito da mesma forma como se fosse um vetor alocado estaticamente: `vetor[0]`, `vetor[1]` e assim por diante.

Caso precise alterar o tamanho do vetor em tempo de execução (dinamicamente), você pode usar a função `realloc`, por exemplo, para aumentar o tamanho do vetor alocado para `20`:

`vetor = realloc(vetor, 20 * sizeof(int));`

Não esqueça de incluir a biblioteca `<stdlib.h>` que contém as funções de alocação dinâmica.

**Importante:** Esse espaço alocado não será mais liberado a não ser que você explicitamente libere com o comando `free(vetor)`. Se você esquecer de desalocar e perder a referência para o ponteiro do vetor, seu programa terá memória desperdiçada que você não conseguirá mais recuperar. Isso acontece para memória alocada dinamicamente.

Os sistemas operacionais modernos desalocam a memória do seu programa (inclusive a que foi perdida) após a execução dele, mesmo que você esqueça de desalocar manualmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, foi de grande ajuda para mim.