# Como mudar o tamanho de um vetor de estruturas global em C?

Tags: c, array, struct

Minha ideia é declarar um vetor global de uma estrutura x, mas eu só terei o tamanho do vetor na main. Como eu posso declarar o vetor e depois dizer qual o tamanho dele? Eu tenho uma solução equivalente em Java, mas não em C.

Comment: De uma olhada nas respostas desta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81977/27190) que mostra como vc pode usar o `malloc` para alocar memória conforme a sua necessidade.

Comment: Tentou fazer alguma coisa? Não tem muito segredo. Tem alguma dúvida específica?

Answer (score 0):

Seguem duas possíveis soluções para o seu problema:

**1)** Solução com alocação dinâmica do vetor com as funções `malloc()` e `free()` da biblioteca padrão `stdlib.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foobar_s
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} foobar_t;


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    foobar_t * v = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* Recupera tamanho do vetor passado como parametro na linha de comando */
    n = atoi( argv[1] );

    /* Aloca memoria necessaria para armazenar o vetor */
    v = (foobar_t*) malloc( n * sizeof(foobar_t) );

    /* Inicializa todos os membros de cada elemento do vetor com o valor '0' */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        v[i]->a = 0;
        v[i]->b = 0;
        v[i]->c = 0;
    }

    /* Faz alguma coisa com o vetor... */

    /* Libera memoria alocada */
    free( v );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

**2)** Solução com alocação estática do vetor utilizando `VLAs (Variable Length Array)` permitidas a partir do padrão `C99`:

```
typedef struct foobar_s
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} foobar_t;


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* Recupera tamanho do vetor passado como parametro na linha de comando */
    n = atoi( argv[1] );

    /* Declara vetor estaticamente com tamanho 'n' */
    foobar_t v[ n ];

    /* Inicializa todos os membros de cada elemento do vetor com o valor '0' */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        v[i].a = 0;
        v[i].b = 0;
        v[i].c = 0;
    }

    /* Faz alguma coisa com o vetor... */

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Mas na solução (2) o array `v` não será local à função main?