# Alocação dinâmica com uma função void

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Fiz um código simples utilizando alocação dinâmica. Apenas pede o tamanho do vetor, para inserir dados e os imprime no final

Eu consigo fazer a alocação dinâmica com `int`, retornando o `vet`, mas como estou aprendendo, estou tentando fazer umas coisas diferentes...

Não sei se e muito absurdo eu tentar fazer isso. Mas conseguem me explicar o porque disso não funcionar?

```
void alocavet(int tam, int *vet){
    vet = (int*) malloc (tam * sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int *vet, tam, *p;

    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);

    alocavet(tam, vet);

    p = vet;

    printf("Entre com os elementos do vetor: ");
    for (int c=0; c<tam; c++) scanf("%d", &*p++);

    p = vet;

    printf("Elementos do vetor: ");
    for (int c=0; c<tam; c++) printf("%d ", *p++);
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é nenhum absurdo.

Em bibliotecas de função, é muito comum ter rotinas que cuidam de alocação e desalocação de espaço de memória, principalmente para estruturas mais complexas.

O que está errado aqui é o seu entendimento sobre a passagem de ponteiro por argumento de função. Vou explicar.

Na função `main()`, você declarou um ponteiro `vet` para um inteiro, mas esse ponteiro ainda não foi inicializado:

```
int *vet, tam, *p;
```

Já a função `alocavet()` espera receber o endereço de um espaço de memória por meio de um ponteiro, também de nome `vet`:

```
void alocavet(int tam, int *vet)
```

Então, você chama `alocavet()` em `main()` e passa para o `vet` de `alocavet()` um endereço inválido, conteúdo que estava lá no espaço de memória da variável não inicializada.

Mas isso não importa muito. Logo na primeira linha de `alocavet()`, o endereço inválido recebido por `vet` é substituído pelo endereço do novo espaço de memória retornado por `malloc()`.

```
void alocavet(int tam, int *vet){
    vet = (int*) malloc (tam * sizeof(int));
}
```

Quando `alocavet()` retorna, o ponteiro `vet` em `main()` **continua apontando para coisa alguma**, pois ainda não foi inicializado. E aí, no primeiro loop, você usa esse endereço inválido em `scanf`, o que faz o programa quebrar.

O que aconteceu com a alocação feita por `alocavet()`?

Ainda está lá, mas perdeu a única referência que tinha. O ponteiro `vet` de `alocavet()` foi destruído quando a função retornou.

Eu sei. Você esperava que `alocavet()` fosse alterar o conteúdo apontado por `vet` de `main()`.

Um jeito de resolver isso é usando ponteiro de ponteiro:

```
void alocavet(int tam, int **vet){
    *vet = (int*) malloc (tam * sizeof(int));
}
```

Desta forma, `vet` de `main()` continuaria sendo declarado do mesmo jeito, como um ponteiro para um inteiro:

```
int *vet;
```

E você passaria o endereço deste ponteiro `vet` usando o operador `&`:

```
alocavet(tam, &vet);
```

Isso é suficiente para inicializar o ponteiro em `main()` e, além disso, obter o retorno de `malloc()`, para checar caso a alocação seja malsucedida, como disseram aqui, e também liberar memória depois de usada.

Veja como ficou:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alocavet(int tam, int **vet) {
  *vet = (int *) malloc ( tam * sizeof(int));
}

void desalocavet(int **vet) {
  if (*vet) {
    free(*vet);
    *vet = 0;
  }
}

int main(){
    int *vet, tam, *p;

    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);

    alocavet(tam, &vet);

    if (vet == NULL) abort();

    p = vet;

    printf("Entre com os elementos do vetor: ");
    for (int c=0; c<tam; c++) scanf("%d", &*p++);

    p = vet;

    printf("Elementos do vetor: ");
    for (int c=0; c<tam; c++) printf("%d ", *p++);

    desalocavet(&vet);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é um absurdo fazer isto. Mesmo para aprender não parece adequado, porque está aprendendo a fazer errado algo que não deve ser feito. Inclusive é mais fácil fazer do jeito certo. E o fato de ter feito do jeito errado deu margem para ficar mais errado ainda já que não liberou a memória. Ok que isto é só um exercício e não causará mal algum, o código termina logo e a memória é liberada pelo SO, porém dá a impressão que nunca precisa e aprender fazer errado. O mesmo vale para verificar se a alocação foi bem sucedida, que é necessária em código real, mas em exercício está ok.

O fato de ter uma função sem retorno de resultado (`void`) nada tem a ver com isso. Raramente é interessante alocar memória dentro de uma função se vai precisar do dado ali onde chama a função alocadora. Aloque sempre onde vai usar o dado. Você pode passar uma alocação para frente, mas não para trás.

É possível fazer isto como uma abstração, mas precisa entender bem o que está fazendo, o que não é o caso.

Este caso possivelmente nem precisaria de uma alocação dinâmica. Até precisa porque pede um `int`, mas é improvável que vá alocar mais do que cabe em um `short`, ou mesmo em um `char`. E isto cabe no *stack*, portanto a alocação no *heap* seria desnecessária. Ok, entendo que seja só por exercício, mas é bom deixar isto claro para não aprender errado.

Não é a primeira vez que vejo código seu mudando o endereço do vetor em vez de usar um índice. Ou seja, não está evoluindo, reveja o jeito como está aprendendo.

Se deseja aprender coisas diferentes procure pro problemas diferentes reais. Aprender o erro é aprender, mas aprender errado não é.

Neste caso não tem porque fazer mais que isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int tam;
    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    int *vet = malloc(tam * sizeof(int));
    printf("\nEntre com os elementos do vetor:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    printf("Elementos do vetor:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) printf("%d ", vet[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VhSggm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mlrmpxgf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/AllocationArray.c).

Comment: Eu não entendi o motivo de ser absurdo uma função [void] fazer uma alocação dinâmica. Poderia me explicar, por favor?

Comment: @slayerowner ser `void`é completamente irrelevante, ignore o título na pergunta.

Comment: Eu não acredito que seja irrelevante, porque o `void` é um tipo de dado que pode ser utilizado para apontar para qualquer outro [tipo de dado] – Assim como o `NULL` está para `(void *)0`. Contudo, esta seria a razão de fazer casting em `malloc()`, já que o mesmo é um ponteiro de função do tipo `void`.

Comment: @slayerowner não, você está confundindo as coisas, uma coisa (`void`) não tem a ver com outra (`void *`). Não se deve fazer *casting* no `malloc()`, isso é um erro cometido por iniciantes. E continua sendo irrelevante para a pergunta dela, leia a pergunta e veja se acha alguma relevância.

Answer (score 4):

Não há a necessidade de *encapsular* a função `malloc`, ainda mais desta forma, você até poderia obter o retorno dela, no entanto, teria que avaliar o ganho e considerar o contexto, mas como é aprendizagem pode usar só `malloc`.

Abaixo segue o código para alocar o bloco de memória para o `vetor`, veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int i;
  size_t tam;
  int *vetor;
  printf("Tamanho:");
  scanf("%zu", &tam);
  vetor = malloc(tam * sizeof * vetor);
  if (vetor == NULL) 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
    vetor[i] = i + 1;
  for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) 
    printf("%i\n", vetor[i]);
  free(vetor);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de checar o retorno da função `malloc`, sendo `NULL` no caso de houver uma falha na alocação, e no caso de sucesso o *endereço* que aponta para o bloco alocado pela função. E quando terminar de usar a variável alocada pela função use a função `free()` para desalocar o bloco de memória que foi alocado anteriormente.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@drmcarvalho/KnottyRoundedCircle).

Tem uma pergunta minha a [respeito do assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81977/27190).

Aprenda mais [sobre o malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/?kw=malloc) e a função [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).